# Bazel + Angular + SocketIO Causes: Uncaught TypeError: XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, socket.io, bazel

I want to add [ngx-socket-io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io) to my Angular application. I use Bazel to run my Angular dev-server.
Unfortunately `ngx-socket-io` doesn't seem to work with the `ts_devserver` out of the box. I get this error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor
    at ts_scripts.js?v=1587802098203:16776
    at Object.23.../transport (ts_scripts.js?v=1587802098203:16780)
    at o (ts_scripts.js?v=1587802098203:11783)
```

It seems to be caused by [xmlhttprequest-ssl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest-ssl) which is a dependency of [engine.io-client](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client/blob/master/package.json) and it is needed by `ngx-socket-io`. But this problem only occurs with the [ts_devserver](https://github.com/flolu/bazel-socketio-issue/blob/525ca3124cb35ccf94f685c7e16b4a83bf502278/BUILD.bazel#L48). **Running the Angular app in [production](https://github.com/flolu/bazel-socketio-issue/blob/525ca3124cb35ccf94f685c7e16b4a83bf502278/BUILD.bazel#L118) works totally fine.**

## Minimal Reproduction

You can easily try it yourself: https://github.com/flolu/bazel-socketio-issue

Just run `yarn install` and then `yarn dev` (it causes the error in the browser console @ http://localhost:4200).
And note that `yarn prod` @ http://localhost:8080 works just fine!

## Edit 1

Currently there seems to be another issue on Windows. So you can only try the example repo if you're running Mac or Linux

Comment: i checked out this repository, yarn dev and yarn prod both are failing with some bazel error.

Comment: https://imgur.com/25YnZXP getting this error.

Comment: Damn. This has probably something to do with Windows (I use Linux and don't get this error)

Comment: can you give a repo, which can work on windows?

Comment: @AakashGarg I don't use windows on any of my devices. So I can't debug the issue

Comment: Running on windows and see exactly the error on console.log. But I don't know how to fix it :(

Comment: @trungk18 that's unfortunate. could you rerun the command with the `--verbose_failures` flag and provide the log output?

Comment: Sure, let me try that. I will keep you updated.

Comment: I run with the flag verbose but didn't see much. Btw, I am running it on Windows 10. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqRb3sHXSFx6jbZ5DhruachcakTuVA?e=Ac8ybW

Comment: @trungk18 great, this is exactly what is supposed to happen! and my question is about the error in the browser console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem comes from `engine.io-client`, which is used internally by `socket.io-client`:

When `socket.io-client` gets built as UMD module triggered by

```
     "@npm//socket.io-client:socket.io-client__umd",
```

in `BUILD.bazel`, the `browser` key of `engine.io-client/package.json`:

```
 "browser": {
   "ws": false,
   "xmlhttprequest-ssl": "./lib/xmlhttprequest.js"
 },
```

is seemingly ignored.

As a consequence, the `require('xmlhttprequest-ssl')` statements in `node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/*.js` remain in the UMD build. Because `xmlhttprequest-ssl` is intended for headless Node environments and does not work in browsers, this results in an error.

I couldn't find a reason/issue for this behavior, but I found a solution (which shouldn't be considered as a workaround):

Rewrite `engine.io-client` with a `postinstall` script:

1. install `shelljs` package: `yarn add -D shelljs`
2. update `postinstall` in `package.json` to: `"postinstall": "node --preserve-symlinks --preserve-symlinks-main ./postinstall-patches.js && ngcc"`
3. put the following code into `postinstall-patches.js` at project root:

```js
try {
  require.resolve('shelljs');
} catch (e) {
  // We are in an bazel managed external node_modules repository
  // and the resolve has failed because node did not preserve the symlink
  // when loading the script.
  // This can be fixed using the --preserve-symlinks-main flag which
  // is introduced in node 10.2.0
  console.warn(
      `Running postinstall-patches.js script in an external repository requires --preserve-symlinks-main node flag introduced in node 10.2.0. ` +
      `Current node version is ${process.version}. Node called with '${process.argv.join(' ')}'.`);
  process.exit(0);
}

const {set, cd, sed, ls} = require('shelljs');
const path = require('path');
const log = console.info;

log('===== about to run the postinstall-patches.js script     =====');
// fail on first error
set('-e');
// print commands as being executed
set('-v');

cd(__dirname);

log('\n# patch engine.io-client: rewriting \'xmlhttprequest-ssl\' to browser shim');
ls('node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/*.js').forEach(function (file) {
  sed('-i', '\'xmlhttprequest-ssl\'', '\'../xmlhttprequest\'', file);
});

log('===== finished running the postinstall-patches.js script =====');
```

(Inspiration: https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_nodejs/#patching-the-npm-packages, which links to the example https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/tools/postinstall-patches.js)

4. `yarn install`
5. `yarn dev`

I'll submit a pull request to your GitHub repro in a few minutes.

---

*Possible* alternatives, couldn't get them to work:

- use `socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js` but with an additional "UMD shim" because it seems to be an "anonymous UMD" module, OR
- some `npm_umd_bundle` magic

See issue [Every new npm dep needs a unique approach how to add it to ts_devserver #1055](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/issues/1055) in [`bazelbuild/rules_nodejs`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs) for more information about both ways.

Comment: PR has been submitted

Comment: wow! I've just tried it and it works perfectly! I still have two questions: (1) you said "which shouldn't be considered as a workaround". do you mean that this shouldn't be used or that it is okay to use it? (2) the patching of the `engine.io-client` might also be done with something like [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) with a .patch file?

Comment: First: I'm just started with Bazel yesterday :-) To (1): I think patching is very OK, see "Patching the packages" at <https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_nodejs/>. I also found many issues where people needed to work around the pre-packaged builds published on NPM. So regarding the Bazel ecosystem, it's a fact that this is needed so there are tools and tricks like this. (2) Yes, should work. Alternative: see "Patching the built-in release" on the linked page. `postinstall-patches.js` gives you more flexibility and is more stable to future upgrades (e.g. we patch without hardcoded filenames).

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll wait until tomorrow before giving out the bounty :)
What was your process of "detecting" the issue? I knew it had something to do with `xmlhttprequest` but, how did you drill it down to `engine.io-client`?

Comment: I knew that `xmlhttprequest-ssl` is not intended for use in browser, so I wondered why it still was required when running the dev server. Finally, a small grep (ripgrep, more specifically: `rg -ul xmlhttprequest-ssl`) revealed references to `xmlhttprequest-ssl` in `socket.io-client` (but there not within its sources, only in the sourcemaps) and `engine.io-client`.

Comment: Since you have managed to fix this issue it would be awesome if you could take a look at this similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64209912