# Bazel + Angular + SocketIO V3 Causes: Uncaught TypeError: XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, socket.io, xmlhttprequest, bazel

I want to add [socket.io-client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client) (v3) to my Angular application. I use Bazel to build and run Angular. Unfortunately I get this error in the browser console when running the [ts_devserver](https://github.com/flolu/angular-bazel-socketio3-issue/blob/ce03c1a05dd33407494e00669d92ef8db6feb316/client/BUILD.bazel#L60):

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor
TypeError: XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor
    at ts_scripts.js?v=80175740:15476
    at Object.14.../globalThis (ts_scripts.js?v=80175740:15480)
```

I had the same issue when working with Socket.IO v2. **But the [old solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62314197/8586803) doesn't work anymore.**

Also this time, not even running the Angular app in production works.

## Minimal Reproduction

You can try it yourself:  [flolu/angular-bazel-socketio3-issue](https://github.com/flolu/angular-bazel-socketio3-issue/tree/ce03c1a05dd33407494e00669d92ef8db6feb316)

Just run `yarn install` and then `yarn dev`. The error is in the browser console at http://localhost:4200.

And note that there is another error when running the app in [production](https://github.com/flolu/angular-bazel-socketio3-issue/blob/ce03c1a05dd33407494e00669d92ef8db6feb316/client/BUILD.bazel#L180) with `yarn prod` at http://localhost:4000:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Cannot access 'e' before initialization
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'e' before initialization
    at home.module-7db83ffb.js:formatted:953
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea, why [Sebastian's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62314197/11253793) doesn't work anymore. `engine.io-client` didn't change much as I can see and it still has several requires of `"xmlhttprequest-ssl"` which should be substituted with `"../xmlhttprequest"`. And that's what he does in that script. But my node_modules do not change after that script, maybe I'm doing smth wrong.

But anyways, what worked for me is doing exactly the same thing but via `patch-package` (I'm just more used to it for patching node_modules).

As for the production bundle, I managed to get it working after just removing excess require that causes the error in production.

That said, here is the final patch (put it into `patches/engine.io-client+4.0.2.patch`):

```
diff --git a/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/index.js b/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/index.js
index 923223d..1ec2668 100755
--- a/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/index.js
+++ b/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/index.js
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-const XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest-ssl");
+const XMLHttpRequest = require("../xmlhttprequest");
 const XHR = require("./polling-xhr");
 const JSONP = require("./polling-jsonp");
 const websocket = require("./websocket");
diff --git a/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/polling-xhr.js b/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/polling-xhr.js
index 9988b02..a2ff168 100755
--- a/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/polling-xhr.js
+++ b/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/polling-xhr.js
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 /* global attachEvent */
 
-const XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest-ssl");
+const XMLHttpRequest = require("../xmlhttprequest");
 const Polling = require("./polling");
 const Emitter = require("component-emitter");
 const { pick } = require("../util");
@@ -15,7 +15,6 @@ const debug = require("debug")("engine.io-client:polling-xhr");
 function empty() {}
 
 const hasXHR2 = (function() {
-  const XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest-ssl");
   const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest({ xdomain: false });
   return null != xhr.responseType;
 })();
```

Also, don't forget to add patch-package in postinstall step:

```
"postinstall": "patch-package && ngcc"
```